# Can someone help me understand why my TextBox's placeholder doesn't change when RadioButton selected?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My HTML source code for my RadioButtonList :

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="rbMemberType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Customer" Selected >Customer</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="Employee">Employee</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="Supplier">Supplier</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Administrator">Administrator</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My C# code for my RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
 protected void rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (rbMemberType.SelectedValue == "Customer")
    {
        txtUsername.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Customer's Username  *");
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Customer's Password  *");
    }
    else if (rbMemberType.SelectedValue == "Employee")
    {
        txtUsername.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Employee's Username  *");
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Employee's Password  *");
    }
    else if (rbMemberType.SelectedValue == "Supplier")
    {
        txtUsername.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Supplier's Username  *");
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Supplier's Password  *");
    }
    else
    {
        txtUsername.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Administrator's Username  *");
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your Administrator's Password  *");
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do, is eg. If the Employee RadioButton is selected, TxtUsername's placeholder will be "Your Employee's Username" and the TxtPassword's placeholder will be "Your Employee's Password".

My two TextBoxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtUsername"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox class="form-control"  runat="server" id="txtPassword" 
    autocomplete="new-password"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set AutoPostack=true?

Comment: Is the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fired? If you look at the page markup do you accumulate multiple `placeholder` attributes on the elements?

Comment: Try `<asp:RadioButtonList id="rbMemberType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">`

Comment: yeehee thanks guys @hardkoded

Comment: Thanks guys, works now after setting the AutoPostBack to equal to true. :)

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks!

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

To get that change "immediately" you need to enable [AutoPostback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_AutoPostBack), and also declare the [OnSelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) even. With that set, you will get a postback when a radio button is clicked and SelectedIndexChanged will be triggered.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList 
    id="rbMemberType" 
    runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostback="true">
```

Comment: but he is missing the main thing, OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged"  so setting postback only will not work. @hardkodek

Comment: True, added to the answer. Thank you @ShadowWalker

Answer (score 0):

Replace your radio button with the following snippet

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbMemberType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Customer" Selected>Customer</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Employee">Employee</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Supplier">Supplier</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Administrator">Administrator</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

your are missing

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbMemberType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
```